# Java program shortestpath orientdb

Tags: java, orientdb, shortest-path

I have this code in a java program. I have already built the graph, call it and I want to calculate the shortest path but I get nothing. I want this result in the java console. can anyone help me please.....

```
        OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:DB_PATH",  "admin", "admin"); 
    OrientGraph db = factory.getTx();
for ( int i=0; i<=Number_Nodes; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=Number_Nodes;j++) {
            for (Vertex v : db.getVertices("vertexID", i)) {
                for (Vertex v1 : db.getVertices("vertexID", j)) {
                    for (Edge e : db.getEdges()) {
                      if (e.getVertex(Direction.IN).equals(v)) {
                          if (e.getVertex(Direction.OUT).equals(v1)){
                              String query = "select expand(shortestPath("+v+","+v1+",'OUT') ";
                            Iterable<OrientVertex> res = db.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();
                                    while (res.iterator().hasNext()) {
                                        OrientVertex vf = res.iterator().next();

                                        System.out.println("Id="+vf.getProperty("vertexID"));


                           }
                       }

                    }

                }

            }
       }
    }     
}
```

Comment: What language is this? I guess Java. Please add java tag if so to add context.

Comment: I have already built the graph if I put  System.out.println(e); Prints all the  edges. I have problems calculating the shortestpath

Comment: Have you a dataset to reproduce your structure ?

Comment: You should start `j` at `i +1` otherwise you look at the same pairs of vertices twice

Answer (score 0):

In your string query

`"select expand(shortestPath("+v+","+v1+",'OUT') "`

you open 2 brackets but you close only one of them

I tried with this structure

[image]

and with this code

```
for ( int i=0; i<=2; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<=2;j++) {
      for (Vertex v : g.getVertices("vertexID", i)) {
         for (Vertex v1 : g.getVertices("vertexID", j)) {
            for (Edge e : g.getEdges()) {
               if (e.getVertex(Direction.IN).equals(v)) {
                  if (e.getVertex(Direction.OUT).equals(v1)){
                    String query = "select expand(shortestPath('"+v.getId()+"','"+v1.getId()+"','BOTH'))";
                    Iterable<OrientVertex> res = g.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();
                    while (res.iterator().hasNext()) {
                       OrientVertex vf = res.iterator().next();
                       System.out.println("Id="+vf.getProperty("vertexID"));
                    }
               }
            }
         }  
      }
   }
}
```

}

and it worked.

[image]

Hope it helps.